# Django query returning non-unicode strings?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I'm completely baffled by a problem I found today: I have a PostgreSQL database with tables which are not managed by Django, and completely normal queries via QuerySet on these tables. However, I've started getting Unicode exceptions and when I went digging, I found that my QuerySets are returning non-Unicode strings!

Example code:

```
d = Document.objects.get(id=45787)
print repr(d.title), type(d.title)
```

The output of the above statement is a normal string (without the `u` prefix), followed by a `<str>` type identifier. What's more, this *normal* string contains UTF-8 data as expected, in raw byte form! If I call `d.title.decode('utf-8')`, I get valid Unicode strings!

Even more puzzling, *some* of the fields work correctly. This same table / model contains another field, `html_filename` of the same type (`TextField`) which is *returned correctly, as a Unicode string*!

I have *no* special options, the database data is correctly encoded, and I don't even know where to begin searching for a solution. This is Django 1.6.2.

Update:

Database Server encoding is UTF8, as usual, and the data is correctly encoded. This is on PostgreSQL 9.1 on Ubuntu.

Update 2:

I think I may have found the cause, but I don't know why it behaves this way: I thought the database fields were defined with the `text` type, as usual, but instead they are defined as `citext` (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/citext.html). Since the Django model is unmanaged, it looks like Django doesn't interpret the field type as being worthy of converting to Unicode. Any ideas how to force Django to do this?

Comment: What's the output of `SHOW server_encoding;` from a `psql` connection to the same database? What's your PostgreSQL version?

Comment: server_encoding is UTF8, PostgreSQL is 9.1. But... see my edit on `citext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Django will not treat fields of type `citext` as textual and return them as Unicode strings.